# Where is row_id column definition in magento module-sales-rule module source code?

Tags: sales-rule

I looks at salesrule table source code in Magento 2.3.3 vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/etc/db_schema.xml. In that file, it said the table primary key is rule_id column but actually the primary key is row_id. However, I cannot find any row_id text in that module. Where is row_id definition in salesrule table?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are looking at Magento Commerce version. In it one of the main additional features is staging - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rule-cart-scheduled-changes.html. That's why there are additional columns - row_id, created_in, updated_in added by vendor/magento/module-sales-rule-staging.

Comment: thank you, I got it.